# Regex ignore first 12 characters from string

Tags: regex, filter, analytics

I'm trying to create a custom filter in Google Analytic to remove the query parts of the url which I don't want to see. The url has the following structure

```
[domain]/?p=899:2000:15018702722302::NO:::
```

I would like to create a regex which skips the first 12 characters (that is until:**/?p=899:2000**), and what ever is going to be after that replace it with nothing.

So I made this one: https://regex101.com/r/Xgbfqz/1  (which could be simplified to .{0,12}) , but I actually would like to skip those and only let the regex match whatever is going to be after that, so that I'll be able to tell in Google Analytics to replace it with "".

The part in the url that is always the same is

```
?p=[3numbers]:[0-4numbers]
```

Thank you

Comment: In short, can you specify sample input and corresponding output?

Comment: You should be able to *capture* that part of string with [`^/\?p=[0-9]{0,3}:[0-9]{0,4}(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Xgbfqz/2)

Comment: @Elvira: Google Analytics uses RE2 regex engine, not JS.

Comment: I tried your version Wiktor, and added an extra folderpath to it to the beginning. 
^/pls/apex/f\?p=[0-9]{0,3}:[0-9]{0,4}(.*)    However. When I add a custom filter in GA with search and replace,  add the regex to the search string and rReplace string with the value 'TEST', it shows in GA: active page TEST, instead of /pls/apex/f?p=899:3100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your regular expression:**

```
\/\?p=\d{3}\:\d{0,4}(.*)
```

Tested in [Golang RegEx 2](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html) and [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/AV5TEB/1)

It search for /p=###:[optional:####] and capture the rest of the right side string.

---

(extra) JavaScript:

```js
paragraf='[domain]/?p=899:2000:15018702722302::NO:::'
var regex= /\/\?p=\d{3}\:\d{0,4}(.*)/;
var match = regex.exec(paragraf);
alert('The rest of the right side of the string: ' + match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily use `"[domain]/?p=899:2000:15018702722302::NO:::".substr(12)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
/\?p\=\d{3}:\d{0,4}

Which matches just this: ?p=[3numbers]:[0-4numbers]
Not sure about replacing though.

https://regex101.com/r/Xgbfqz/1